# How to prevent Akka LoggingAdapter from truncating ByteString log messages?

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I'm new to Scala with Akka. I'm using LoggingAdapter to log ByteString messages. I see a common scenario where a decently large message gets truncated. For example,

[image]

I need to see the entire message. Please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the ByteString to an array and then print the individual bytes in a space-separated manner.

```
val myArr : Array[Byte] = byteStringMessage.toArray
log.info(s" byte array : ${myArr.mkString(" ")}")
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the logic in `akka.util.ByteString.toString` method:

```scala
override def toString(): String = {
    val maxSize = 100
    if (size > maxSize)
      take(maxSize).toString + s"... and [${size - maxSize}] more"
    else
      super.toString
  }
```

you can convert `ByteString` to `List` and this will print everything.

```scala
val myBs: ByteString = ??? //some very long ByteString
println(myBs) //this will get truncated
println(myBs.toList) //but this will not
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I tried this :   

val myBs: ByteString = rawMessage.bodyByteString    
println(myBs.toList)


Got an error :    

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.toList$(Lscala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized;)Lscala/collection/immutable/List;

Comment: Thanks for bringing the overridden toString() method to notice. It was helpful.
I was able to convert it to an array and use mkString() to print individual entities.